# How do I make it detect exactly how many digits are in a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get my code to show each digit individually on its own line, and it does do that. However, I am getting an error at the end of it, so I want to detect exactly how many digits are in the number. I am having trouble finding a solution for this that isn't len(), because for this specific program I am not supposed to use it.

Here's my code:

```
number = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
number = str(number)
digits = 0
while True:
    print(number[digits])
    digits += 1
```

Comment: `for item in number: digits += 1`. You can also add `print(item)`.

Comment: `digits = [character.isdigit() for character in str(number)]`

Comment: Why do you take a string (`number`), convert it to an integer, and then convert in back to a string?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a counter and with a while loop should look like:

```
num = int(input("enter num"
result = 0

while num > 10:
  num = num // 10
  result += 1

result += 1


print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

It throws an error because you are running an infinite while loop. Use for instead.

```
number = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
number = str(number)
digits = 0
for i in number:
    print(i)
    digits+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `log10` (logarithm with base 10) function:

```
import math
number = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
print(1 + int(math.log10(number)))
```

Comment: I think this computes correctly how many digits are there in "007"? That's why +1

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem just by printing elements of string concatenated with new-line delimiter without attempts to find how many elements in string:

```
number = input("Enter a positive integer: ")
print('\n'.join(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you’re  getting the error is because when the `digits` acquires the value of the length of the number say `l`, then `number[l]` doesn't exist (The indices start from 0)

```
number = input("Enter a positive integer: ")) 

# type(number) is <class 'str'> you don't have to convert to int and reconvert to string

# since <class 'str'> implements iterable you could go like this ..

digits = 0 

for digit in number:

     print(digit)  # digit is still a str here

     digits += 1
```